# What can i do with a stacktrace like this one?

Tags: android

**NOTE: Im not asking for assistance with this specific StackTrace, just asking in general for advice in debugging crashes like this?**

Hi all,

I have a couple crashes like this that don't help me too much?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 632412 bytes
   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3982)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:755)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6520)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 632412 bytes
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:617)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3618)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3974)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:755)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6520)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

It doesn't tell me where the problem is, and with an application with tons of activities and fragments.

How do you figure out where to start with something like this?

Comment: do you have intent.putExtra somehwere in your code? the problem is there maybe, if you are passing an object that is larger than 1mb.. That is not a good thing. If you are passing images/bitmaps to another activity via intent consider different approaches..

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic no, i never pass images between activities/fragments. All our images are hosted so its just the urls.

Answer (score 2):

It probably because of passing more data(>1mb) between activity to activity or services to activity.

To make it sure, you have to analyse where it thrown while your working with your application.

Comment: Thanks, i understand why there was a crash, its just a matter of trying to find it! thats the problem

Answer (score 2):

First look around for: 'Caused by'. This is what actually broke your code.Everything before this line is information how you got to there- which methods in which class lead to this point. Above it usually is how the system created the exceptions.
And for how to fix this problems- google the exceptions/read the docs, this should give you enough insight what actually happened